# Update a div using controller action without recharging the page in ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, controller

I have this action in my controller

```
public ActionResult TestItemLogistic()
    {
        ControlViewModel model = new ControlViewModel();
        model.itemSelected = "Logistic";
        return RedirectToAction("MenuList", model);

    }
```

This action is called once I click on a

```
<a href=@url.Action(subItem.action, subItem.controller)>
```

I want to be able to do all this without recharging the page, and just update some div instead.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to use AJAX. Specifically, I'd take a look at the [jQuery .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using Ajax with jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ above is the docs for jquery ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to replace the contents of the selected element(s) with the HTML output retrieved from a URL.

Say you have

```
<a href="@url.Action(subItem.action, subItem.controller)" id="ClickMe">Click Me</a>
<div id="ReplaceMe"></div>
```

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#ClickMe').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#ReplaceMe').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
 });
</script>
```

Edit: I see now, you want a link to an action, that returns a URL, and then you want to load the contents of that resulting URL.

```
public ActionResult TestItemLogistic()
{
    ControlViewModel model = new ControlViewModel();
    model.itemSelected = "Logistic";

    UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
    return Content(u.Action("MenuList", model));

}


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#ClickMe').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(url) {
              $('#ReplaceMe').load(url);
       });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply this seems to be good solution, I forgot to tell you that the view rendered by the action is the same view. So ideally, I want to execute the action without returning anything and update the div from javascript

Answer (score 0):

You whan to use the Ajax attribute from the view. you can add a link that can update any element by id

```
@Ajax.RouteLink("TestLink", new { controller = "Persoon", action = "Partial" },new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace UpdateTargetId = "Id Element"})
```

try this